# Resolve Vue component names on the fly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm searching for a way to resolve Vue (sfc) component names 'on the fly'. Basically I'm getting kind of component names from a backend and need to translate them into real component names on the frontend. Something like this:

```
<text/> => /components/TextElement.vue
```

or

```
<component v-bind:is="text"></component> => => /components/TextElement.vue
```

The idea is providing a global function that maps the backend names to the frontend names. I don't want to do this in every place where those components are used, so maybe there is a kind of hook to change the names dynamically?

Thanks a lot,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper `<component>` that maps the component names and [globally registers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) the specified component on the fly.

1. Create a component with a `prop` (e.g., named "xIs") for the `<component>`'s `is` property:

   export default {
        props: {
          xIs: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          }
        },
      };
2. Add a template that wraps `<component>`, and a `data` property (e.g., named "translatedName") that contains the mapped component name (from backend to front-end name):

   export default {
        data() {
          return {
            translatedName: ''
          }
        }
      };
3. Add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the `prop` that will register a component by the name indicated in the `prop` value:

   import componentNames from './component-names.json';

      export default {
        watch: {
          xIs: {
            immediate: true, // run handler immediately on current `xIs`
            async handler(value) {
              try {
                const name = componentNames[value];                             // 1. lookup real component name
                if (name) {
                  Vue.component(name, () => import(`@/components/${name}`));    // 2. register component
                  this.translatedName = name;                                   // 3. set name for 
                }
              } catch (e) {
                console.warn(`cannot resolve component name: ${value}`, e);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }